# ASP.NET MVC 5 wrong relative path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing application in ASP.NET MVC 5 framework and I have a problem with my relative paths on the server.

For example my url in the browser: `http://localhost:1176/Account/ForgotPassword`
Where **Account** is a controller
and **ForgotPassword** is an action

But in browser development window I see wrong requests from my css files:
`http://localhost:1176/Account/assets/img/backtop.png`

Correct request should be `http://localhost:1176/assets/img/backtop.png`

Some why application thinks that `http://localhost:1176/ControllerName` is a base directory for application but it's not.

I am understand that I can use a full paths in my css files, such as `/assets/img/backtop.png` but it is not applicable for me because on the host server it can be different than in development ones.

Have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: avoid using hardcoded paths instead use `Url.Content()` helper to provide paths to your files.

Comment: Please add your view code, only the part that contains `/assets/img/backtop.png`

Comment: You can also use the tilda to specify the application root: `~/assets/img/backtop.png`, you can use this directly in your *Views*.

Comment: Create bundles specifying the root paths for JavaScript & CSS, in 'BundleConfig.cs' file in 'App_Start' and include it in your views as '@Styles.Render("~/<your bundle name>")'

In css aswell specify the image paths from root as : '../Images/accent.png', where 'Images' is at root path

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. This is strange for me because I have't that problem before. Tracing all wrong paths can take a huge time for me. Probably I broke something in my project. I will try to find out what was broken.